# ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection with the following error message: "Login failed for user '[SQLLogin]'."

Tags: ssis, package, visual-studio-2019, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

Whenever I deploy the package, it seems like the connection details aren't embedded.

I built a package that executes normally on Visual Studio, but once I deploy it onto the SQL Server, it fails to execute, stating the failure to acquire the connection.

My co-workers have created projects with the .ispac file using the same exact steps/package that I have before deploying, and have been deploying with no issues. I can even execute their packages just fine from SQL Server! It's driving me insane why it seems that only MY deployments aren't executing.

I secured the package by setting the ProtectionLevel to 'SecureAllWithPassword' on both the package and project level before deploying.

The package works if I were to embed the password in the configuration's Connection Manager *afterwards*. It even saves it. However, my co-workers and I have never had to do this in the past and it wasn't standard procedure.

I've checked to see that my steps are no different than the ones my co-workers follow. They were on Visual Studio 2017, and I was on 2019 so I tried swapping to Visual Studio 2017. It still fails to execute with the failure to acquire connection.

Banging my head against a wall scouring for answers across the internet. All seem to describe ProtectionLevel, but I've made sure to set it appropriately.

Comment: When you deploy the .ispac, take a peek at the log/output. You'll see a line in there about changing to server protection level. It has been my experience, that strips the sensitive data, regardless of the development environment protection level settings.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I didn't see the log/output available after deploying (I'm just given a wizard where it shows that it was successful/passed). However, your answer prompted me to take a closer look at what I was actually deploying. From the Solution Explorer, I was right clicking and deploying the actually package (.dstx) and not the entire project folder + packages inside. Small change that made the entire difference. Package executes now but I don't think I would've had the clarity without your answer and taking a break from looking at it for a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deploying from the package file directly (.dstx), deploy the entire project folder with the package inside.